# commandline match part of string

Tags: c#, regex, windows, string, command-line

I have a large number of 15-character alphanumeric strings in a few text files, one per line.  I want to find any strings where the first 11 characters (the last 4 can be anything) are any of the following:

1. All numbers (Ex: 111111111112394, 12345678901PxCJ)
2. All letters, all the same (case sensitive) (Ex: aaaaaaaaaaaXF5r)
3. All letters, can be different (case sensitive) (Ex: abcdefghijkXF5r,
   BAKSFIUQMGAXF5r)
4. All letters, all the same (case insensitive) (Ex: AaaAaAAAaAAXF5r)

I'm very bad at creating regex patterns to begin with, but this is further complicated by

1. only the first 11 characters matter and
2. I would like to be able to use the Windows command-line option
   `FINDSTR` to do this. If `FINDSTR` is insufficient (it uses nonstandard regex), I can write a quick C# program to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should use the following [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
[\w\d]{11,11}

Options: case insensitive

Match a single character present in the list below «[\w\d]{11,11}»
    Exactly 11 times «{11,11}»
    A word character (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
    A single digit 0..9 «\d»
```

**Tools**

No need to create a C# program, just use tools that are out there already.

Try first with http://www.wingrep.com/

Then check out `Alt+F7` in [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)

And I would have to suggest installing [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) to get linux functionalities inside `cmd.exe`